# Java - compile from command line - external jar

Tags: java

I am using this library to compile a java program. I am using eclipse, but I also want to try and compile it from the command line (it will be executed through the command line). Its seems to be working on Eclipse.

I have tried this in the command line and it seems to be working:

```
javac -cp ../lib/jxl.jar Main.java
```

but it gives me this:

```
Main.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Reader
location: class Main
    Reader excel_reader = new Reader();
    ^
Main.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Reader
location: class Main
    Reader excel_reader = new Reader();
```

I just have 2 classes, Main ( that has only the main method ) and a Reader. Both files are under the src/ folder in eclipse workspace.

Reader class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.CellType;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class Reader {
  private String inputFile;

  public void setInputFile(String inputFile) {
    this.inputFile = inputFile;
  }

  public void read() throws IOException  {
    File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile);
    Workbook w;
    try {
      w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
      // Get the first sheet
      Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
      // Loop over first 10 column and lines

      for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getColumns(); j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
          Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
          CellType type = cell.getType();
          if (type == CellType.LABEL) {
            System.out.println("I got a label "
                + cell.getContents());
          }

          if (type == CellType.NUMBER) {
            System.out.println("I got a number "
                + cell.getContents());
          }

        }
      }
    } catch (BiffException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Main Class

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Reader excel_reader = new Reader();
    excel_reader.setInputFile("Excel_Spreadsheets/Dictionary_Part2.xls");
    excel_reader.read();
  }
}
```

Comment: add the eclipse src folder to the classpath you pass to javac

Comment: use `-cp .:../lib/jxl.jar` _assuming you are running this from the source folder since you dont provide a path to Main.java and the code shows no package_

Comment: I thought REader class was automatically added

Comment: I am getting this now: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl/read/biff/BiffException

Comment: Ok fixed it. Had to use java -classpath ../lib/jxl.jar:. Main

Comment: What is :. for? and .: ?