# Java Development Workflow with Text-Editor and Commandline

Tags: java, command-line, text-editor

I want to get started with Java! I have a bit of experience with C/C++ and Python development. For this i'm mainly using Emacs (a text editor) and the commandline, thus not using a heavier weight IDE for those kind of things.

I don't want to adapt my workflow to suit an IDE, but I don't know the Workflow (write, build, test) in Java so I thought about asking here. Searching the Web didn't give me good results.

Can someone give me the the basic workflow when developing Java with my requirements? I use Linux for all my programming. 
Are my requirements/wishes even practical or should i consider using something like IDEA or Eclipse?

Can someone point me to documentation or blog posts about this topic or documents, that give a quick overview and/or examples on how to get started with Java (something for programmers with a little experience in other languages)?

Comment: _Can someone point me to documentation or blog posts..._ Google should be able to do this for you very easily...

Comment: I wouldn't ask here if I didn't try that before!

Comment: _I wouldn't ask here if I didn't try that before!..._ Honestly.. how many effort have you done for your research? There are tons of tutorials and examples around the internet... however your question is off-topic for SO

Comment: What you mean with workflow? The workflow doesn't change with an IDE, you write code, compile it, run it... it's just more comfortable with an IDE, that's all

Comment: @B001ᛦ: Depends on your definition of "easily"... Google will give tons of hits, but without a high-level overview of how things fit together, it's very hard to get started. Thus I wrote an answer to try and add that overview. Now OP can hopefully google successfully :-).

Comment: @B001ᛦ Well i tried to Google for it but soon enough found myself in a situation where i didn't really knew what to actually google for! So i'm very greatful for @ sleske who took the time to andere, now i have a better understanding in how to proceed and i know that my idea of starting with a texteditor was not dumb. Even if it's off topic, i'm glad that i asked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For this I'm mainly using Emacs (a text editor) and the commandline,
>   thus not using a heavier weight IDE for those kind of things.

An IDE has many advantages over a text editor, mainly when navigating, debugging and refactoring code, but it is not required. Actually, working without an IDE is useful to understand the underlying technologies. My advice would be: Start without an IDE, and when everything works, try out some IDEs to see how they help you.

> Can someone give me the the basic workflow when developing Java with
>   my requirements?

The basic workflow is (for any compiled language):

1. write source code
2. build
3. run

In the case of Java, that means:

### 1 Writing source code

You write `.java` files in a text editor, observing the right filesystem layout (file name = class name, directory corresponds to package etc.). You already have that covered.

### 2 Compiling the code

You compile the code using a Java compiler, possibly building a JAR or WAR file (depending on the type of application you are writing). You can do that manually by directly invoking `javac` (see for example [Java - compile from command line - external jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504223/java-compile-from-command-line-external-jar) ), but you should really use a build tool. The best tool to get started is probably [Apache Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) or [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle).

The basic idea is the same with both Maven and Gradle: You write a build file, which essentially describes your project and how to compile it (a POM file in the case of Maven, a build.xml for Gradle), then you can build by just invoking the build tool. The build tool takes care of all the nitty gritty like invoking `javac` etc. Most importantly, both also perform *dependency resolution*, meaning they can automatically download and use libraries that you use in your code.

#### 3 Running

Finally, you run the program from the command line. How to do that depends on the type of program: A simple executable (or a Spring Boot application) can by run using `java -jar myprog.jar`, a WAR file must be deployed to a Servlet container (such as Apache Tomcat).

---

I hope this gives a general overview of **How do I develop without an IDE?**. For more details, look for specific questions here on Stackoverflow (or elsewhere), read the docs, and if all fails ask a more specific question here :-).

Comment: Thank you, that's a big help for me!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @sleske : if you really want to learn the language, it's good to start with a text editor. Later on you can use an IDE but by then you will know how the build process works and what exactly the IDE is doing. There exists no magic in coding. If something works but you don't understand why, it will certainly fail one day :)

Maybe some nice feature: I use Eclipse and added a [vim plugin](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/documentation/) :)
And if you learn some useful shortcuts you can write code really fast (without a mouse)

Comment: That's exactly the reason, why i want to start learning the language with a text-editor! At my university we are forced to work with Visual Studio, which is not a bad product by any means, it just generates so many files that i really struggled with learning because i thought that every file is important and didn't understand a thing!

Comment: Good luck with java. Let's hope one day you will be experienced enough to help others on this site.

Comment: Upvoted for the mention of vim (just kidding, great answer). Note however that OP uses the Wrong Editor (tm) (meaning an editor that is not vim), so they may need some convincing to come over from the dark side and use vim :-).

Answer (score -1):

You should download IntelliJ directly:

- certain best practices like `static import` make your code more readable because you read it with a smart IDE. If you read code just with vim, the navigation between classes is not possible.
- you have an easy access to a terminal and perform certain Maven or Gradle commands here.

I would not say the same with other languages (css, html).